# Questions for Windows 8+

Tags: app, windows

### Screenshot

[image: Questions screenshot.]

### About

*Questions* is a very simple reader for Stack Exchange network websites.

It works very easy:

- First, you select your favorite Stack Exchange websites.
- Then, you select the tags you are interested on.
- Finally, questions are listed on the screen.

#### How is this app different from other reader apps?

*Questions* focuses on the questions you may be able to answer, not in a bunch of questions you may not even have time to go through. It is handy, it is in your *start screen* and in your *lock screen*.

Do not miss any other question.

#### Features

- If you give *lock screen access* to the app, questions are updated every 15 minutes.
- If you choose **Questions** as you *detailed status app* in the *lock screen settings*, you will see the latest question in your lock screen.
- Click **mark all as read** to dismiss the current displayed questions.
- Snap **Questions** on one side and your browser in the other side to browse through the questions more comfortable.

#### License

Questions for Windows 8+ by [kiewic.com](http://kiewic.com/questions) is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).

#### Download

[Download **Questions** from the Windows Store](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/questions/ec6e62be-d597-4d61-a932-21f2936d2be3).

The first release is already out, please give it a try.

#### Platform

Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

### Contact

Not getting what you paid for? Maybe you downloaded the wrong app, **Questions** is free. It only costs battery and bandwidth. Still want to contact me? The best way to do it is to [send me a message on Facebook](http://facebook.com/kiewic).

### Code

This app is written in Windows Runtime C#.

Are you interested in the source code? Take a look at https://github.com/kiewic/questions